# How to insert data into a partitioned parquet table using imapala shell

Tags: hadoop, hive, impala

How to insert data into a partitioned parquet table using imapala shell

Comment: what errors are you getting, may be you didnt enable dynamic partitioning or you can load data in nonpartitioned temporory table and use that to load your partitioned table

Comment: I'm not getting any error while loading, but i'm not being able to query the table. it says "unsupported file type found" How do i enable dynamic partitioning?

Comment: If you aren't having an error loading the table then you should update your question. You are asking about ways to load a partitioned table but you comment saying you are having query errors. Please post some code examples of what you are trying to accomplish so it is clear as to what you are trying to do.

Comment: edited the question